# Require all files based on ancestors

Tags: ruby, autoload

I am working on non-rails ruby project. The project structure is something like below:

```
--Root
  -Base
   -xyz_base.rb
   -abc_base.rb
  -Entities
    -A
     -base
      -a_base.rb
     -a.rb
    -B
     -b.rb
    -C
     -c.rb
  -app.rb
```

in app.rb I have something like below:

```
Dir['./**/'].each {|dir| $:.push dir}
Dir["./**/*.rb"].each {|rb| require rb}
```

So, All files are included in project (`abc_base.rb`,`a.rb`,...).

The problem is, It does not know which one should be required before another. For example, `a_base.rb` needs to be required before `a.rb`. But, in action, it first requires `a.rb` and in `a_base.rb` I get `uninitialized constant Entities::A::Base (NameError)` or `cannot load such file`.

I have looked into `autoload`, `require_all` gem. And also another solution is to put require in each file to only require needed file. But files are too much.

Is there any idea?

Comment: Whats the algorithm of this `require` project? Sub-Directory content should be required before the actual content of the directory?

Comment: Have a look at [Bundler](http://bundler.io/).

Answer (score 0):

If you know you'll be using this naming convention throughout your project - and don't want to use your proposed solution (explicitly require a_base from a) - you could do something similar to the following:

```
Dir.glob("**/[a-z].rb").each do |file| 
  m = /(.+)\.rb/.match(file)
  require_relative "#{m[1]}_base.rb" # entities/a/a_base.rb
  require_relative file
end
```